# Show that ABA=0 if and only if B is of the form C-PCP for some symmetric matrix C

Tags: self-study, matrix, linear-algebra

If **B** is a symmetric matrix such that **ABA** is well-defined, then show that **ABA=0** if and only if **B** is of the form **C-P<sub>A</sub>CP<sub>A</sub>** for some symmetric matrix **C**.

***P<sub>A</sub>** here is the projection matrix of **A**.*

Comment: but the part "iff B is of the form C-PCP" just confuses me.

Comment: **This assertion is not generally true.** Consider the case $$B=\pmatrix{1&0\\0&1};\quad A=\pmatrix{0&1\\0&0}.$$  I suspect you intend to refer to $ABA^\prime$ and, for $P_A$ to be meaningful, you either need to assume $A$ also is symmetric or else replace $A$ by $(A+A^\prime)/2$ everywhere.